# Run a php Script from a form in google App Engine

Tags: php, web-services, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App engine, so stuck. I want to run a php script to process my form in google app engine. I am not sure how to go about it.

This is how I have defined the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/php/" name="SampleForm">
                            <input type="hidden" name="env_report" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT,AUTH_TYPE,REMOTE_USER" />
                            <input id="TEST" type="text" name ="EmailAddr" class="text" value="Your email address" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your email address';}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Sample FormMail Testing" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value="helloworld@gmail.com" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
                        </form>
```

and this is my app.yaml :

```
application: totemic-gravity-676
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /
  script: main.php


- url: /php/
  script: formmail.php
```

what my php script does is that it sends a mail to some email address. I have my formmail.php in the same level as app.yaml. But this does not work. The script can be accessed statically, but when I run it via the form, I get error messages. What could be the problem ?

you may check it in action here :http://totemic-gravity-676.appspot.com/ (scroll down to the update form)

I think I have do something with the -static keyword in my yaml, but I am clueless about how to define a folder as static

Comment: Your app.yaml file looks fine.

What error are you getting in the App Engine logs?

Comment: I dont seem to be getting any errors :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're script is being called - looks like you're trying to use the mail() function that isn't supported on app engine.

1. from your app logs.

   /formmail.php 200 350ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36 module=default version=1

   W 2014-08-25 19:32:57.768 The function 'mail' is not implemented.

   W 2014-08-25 19:32:57.768 The function 'mail' is not implemented.

   W 2014-08-25 19:32:58.046 The function 'mail' is not implemented.
2. to send mail on app engine using php

[Mail API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/)

Comment: i added a link in the answer on how to send mail using app engine.

Comment: yes, I saw it. Just one more thing, how do I send mail to Admin(so that my admin quota is used ?)

Comment: Use AdminMessage: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/google.appengine.api.mail.AdminMessage

Comment: Thank you for both the answers